# signed applet on https server accesses crossdomain xml @port 80, access denied

Tags: java, security, applet

I have a problem, my applet is signed and crossdomian xml was put at the root of the apache server. Application is accessed through apache https server. If my application(www.dns.com) is accessed with in the network, it works fine. If application accessed from out side network, **javascript call to applet changes dns to ip address with port 80, where as my application is https with default port 443**. So, my application is failing.

my crossdomain xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross- domain-    policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135138/access-denied-java-net-socketpermission-127-0-0-18080-connect-resolve/6061224#6061224) gives more info.

Any ideas.. please.

Answer (score 0):

Since your applet is signed, the `crossdomain.xml` file should not be necessary.  You can use `AccessController.doPrivileged` to wrap the code that needs this permission.

Otherwise, as you say, you are forced to serve up the `crossdomain.xml` file on port 80 at the IP address, not your domain name, if that is different for your server configuration.

These options are noted in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135138/access-denied-java-net-socketpermission-127-0-0-18080-connect-resolve/6061224) you linked to.