# Security Exception in self signed sound recorder Applet

Tags: applet, javasound, signed-applet

I have created an applet for recording sound. It throws an exception when I try to open a dataline.

```
TargetDataLine.open()
```

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (javax.sound.sampled.AudioPermission record)

My applet is self signed, all other jar files are self signed.

Previously I was using a different thread to start the `TargetDataLine` and close the line. Afterwords instead of creating another thread, I switched to `Executorservice`. It works fine with thread but throws above exception with `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the executor service starts a new thread when there is call from javascript, the security level of the thread is set to that of javascript thread.

So using AccessControl.doPrivilaged helps to solve the problem.[Explained here how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135138/access-denied-java-net-socketpermission-127-0-0-18080-connect-resolve)