# Java SAXParserFactory and XMLParserConfiguration file not found

Tags: java, xml, applet

I'm running a java applet that is supposed to upload a picture to a website, the uploading fails and gives the following exception:

```
 java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 192.168.10.25 resolve)
```

And the backlog shows that the files `SAXParserFactory` and `XMLParserConfiguration` can not be found.

I've tried creating the `crossdomain.xml` file and granting open permissions but it didnt work. I've also added some mapping to the hosts file coz I thought it maybe the system can not map when access through the ip address but still no difference.

Any help?

Comment: I referred to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135138/access-denied-java-net-socketpermission-127-0-0-18080-connect-resolve

Comment: Is the applet digitally signed?  Unless the JRE can sure the applet is 'phoning home' it will be refused in a sand-boxed applet.

Comment: no it is not signed, do you have an easy way to sign them?

Comment: What is the hard way?  [This demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) has a build file that creates a certificate and digitally signs the code (using the tools in the SDK).

Comment: I signed the jar file, but still getting the same error.I suspect that the website even felt a change. I replaced the jar file with the signed one and uploaded it to the server. Any help?

Comment: Were you prompted to accept the signed code?  Where is the applet page, at what URL?

Comment: I can't post the url because it's an internal website and no I wasn't prompted to accept the signed code.I verified that the jar is signed and the replaced the old jar with the signed one and restarted the servers.What step am I missing?

Comment: It's deplyed on  WEB Sphere Application server 6

Comment: *"I wasn't prompted to accept the signed code."* Then the browser does not yet know there is a new Jar.  (Restart the browser) go to the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) & type `x` to clear the class cache (or is it `c`?  I always use them together).  Then reload the applet and make sure you see [dialogs like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12986334/418556).

Answer (score 0):

if it is an access restriction issue, try to put your code that access the file as follows;

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
        public Object run() {
            // privileged code goes here, for example:

        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there other work around? I don't have access to the source code